Shelves in concrete+drywall
Before I absolutely wreck a wall at work I need some insight:
I’m familiar with the process/drill/bits/anchors associated with installing shelves in concrete so I don’t have questions about that part, but the wall I’m working with is a cinder block wall that’s been covered by drywall.
Is there anything I need to do differently because of the drywall or can I just go about it the same way I would if it was concrete only?

Well, the answer is: it depends.  Are you intending to anchor the shelves to the studs that the drywall is undoubtedly fastened to, or to anchor the shelves through the drywall, to the CMU?  (OK, I suppose there's a small chance the drywall is simply glued directly to the CMU.)

You need not worry about the drywall assuming you anchor to the block. It can handle static compression which you get at the low end of the shelf bracket.  (The high end is under tension, handled by the anchor.)
That said, you've used cinder and concrete when referring to the block, and which it is does make a difference.  For both, you would want to drill into the center of the web of the block, not the edge by the void or the face over the void.  For cinder, that would be more important because it is more likely to crack and crumble.

Perfect, thank you so much! I appreciate this more than you know :)

Great!  please don't forget to mark the question as answered
